# Function never calls the second function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript code

```
function editRerenderFix() {
  console.log("edit render start");
  textAreaFix();
  console.log("edit render middle");
  setupDates();
  console.log("edit render end");
}
/** Function to auto expand out the text area to hold all content **/
function textAreaFix() {
  jQuery('textarea').on( 'change keyup keydown paste cut', function (event){
    jQuery(this).height(100);
    jQuery('textarea').each(function() {
      jQuery(this).height(jQuery(this).prop('scrollHeight'));
    });
  });
  return null;
}
/** Function to fix and set the custom date/time picker **/
function setupDates() {
  jQuery('.dateFormat').remove();
  var inputs = jQuery('.inputDate');
  jQuery(inputs).each(function() {
    var input = jQuery(this).val().split('/')[2];
    if(input.length > 4) {
      input = input.split(" ")[0];
    }
    if(input < '2015') {
      jQuery(this).val("");
    }
  });
  console.log("Setup Dates function ran");
  jQuery('.inputDate').datetimepicker();
}
```

This function is called using the onComplete ajax method. The problem is that when it runs only `textAreaFix()` is called. In the console only "edit render start" and "edit render middle" show up.

[image]

The reason that "Setup Date function ran" first is because I have this function,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.material.init();
  textAreaFix();
  setupDates();
  tourStep();
  easterEgg();
});
```

How can I get the `setupDates()` function called?

EDIT:

I added more debugging to `setupDates()`,

```
/** Function to fix and set the custom date/time picker **/
function setupDates() {
  jQuery('.dateFormat').remove();
  var inputs = jQuery('.inputDate');
  console.log(inputs);
  jQuery(inputs).each(function() {
    var input = jQuery(this).val().split('/')[2];
    console.log(input);
    if(input.length > 4) {
      console.log("Input > 4");
      input = input.split(" ")[0];
      console.log(input);
    }
    if(input < '2015') {
      console.log("Fix 2015 dates");
      jQuery(this).val("");
    }
  });
  console.log("Setup Dates function ran");
  jQuery('.inputDate').datetimepicker();
}
```

When I run this I get,

[image]

I am not sure where the "undefined" comes from though.

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: No errors at all. The function is just never called. I snipped the console. The first Setup Dates function is on page load and the edit render start is when I clicked the button that calls the ajax method.

Comment: You can apply breakpoints in the code and see whether the code is getting halted. Use developer tools available with the browser.

Comment: Your setupDates() seems to be called as we can see "Setup Dates function ran" in your console. But it's weird that it appears before 'edit render start'. Is it really editRerenderFix() that is called on your onComplete ?

Comment: Your code is rising exception, sometimes you don't see any output in error console. Check with debug tools the wrong line

Comment: Based on your console.log output, there is an error in setupDates() if the "edit render end" never shows up.  Reality is, setupDates() probably is being called but there's an error in your code.  Sprinkle some more console.log statements into setupDates() for further troubleshooting.  I'm speculatin that the error is on your split() statements.  I've been in plenty of situations where I assumed a string had a certain character, so I split on that character and grab the first element of it, only to find out later that I stumbled on a circumstance where the split character was missing.

Comment: jQuery(inputs) should be rising an exception, because inputs is **already** a jQuery object, therefore it is parsed as jQuery(jQuery(something)). perhaps that's the error? Shouldn't it be `inputs.each(function()` ?

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf I added more code to address your concerns.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle or plunkr or CodePen.

Comment: I agree with @RobinLeboeuf, I'm thinking that `editRerenderFix` is not getting ran but something similar is. Either that or there must be an error on the page that you are not catching. If debugging with Chrome Developer Tools (or similar), make sure that you are not filtering out errors, warnings, etc.

Comment: what if you add a `console.log('test')` right after `function setupDates()` , does it run?

Comment: I added quite a few debug statements to `setupDates()` and included the new console output. Thanks for all the help!! @KJPrice I do not have any filters applied, good thought.

Comment: My guess is that it is displaying undefined because the loop is repeating and jQuery(this).val().split('/')[2] is causing a problem.  Maybe console.log on this and this.val() right at the beginning of the loop's block?

Comment: You don't need to do jQuery(inputs) as inputs is already an array of jquery objects.  Also don't think you need quotes around `if (input < '2015')` you should try `if (input < 2015)` or `if (parseInt(input) < 2015)`

Comment: @JamesNearn That found it! The second input on the page did not have html value added to its markup. Thanks!!

Comment: Awesome - glad it's working for you :)  Great job to everybody else as well! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it is displaying undefined because the loop is repeating and jQuery(this).val().split('/')[2] is causing a problem. Maybe console.log on this and this.val() right at the beginning of the loop's block? –  James Nearn 30 mins ago